# Max memory allocation on AWS EBS

Tags: java, memory-management, jvm, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, heap-memory

I am using ElasticBeanstalk to host my Grails app. 
As of now I am using m1.small instance which has 1.7 GiB of main Memory. My question is what is the MaxHeap and Max PermGen I can allocate to my instance? As of now my configuration looks like below

```
Initial JVM heap size: 512m
JVM command line options: -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
Maximum JVM heap size: 512m
Maximum JVM permanent generation size: 256m
```

Any suggestion for selecting the optimum numbers so that I can use max memory for my Tomcat and still have enough left for the OS itself?

Rephrasing the question what is the MAX out of 1.7 GiB can I allocate to something other than the OS(tomcat in this case)

Answer (score 0):

You really need to profile your application stack.

It's easy to increase the size of the heap above the amount of physical memory by adding swap which increases Virtual memory.
For performance you want to find the right fit between instance and application.

Run your application stack in a vagrant instance first and **measure it**.  Adapt until
you get consistent performance, but `m1.small` instances may be slowed down by others on the same physical host.

That said, you can run top, and sort on Virtual memory.

Example: (Compare VIRT, RES, and SHR columns)

```
 PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
1220 root      20   0  308m 1316  868 S  0.0  0.3   0:00.43 VBoxService
1126 root      20   0  243m 1576 1040 S  0.0  0.3   0:00.02 rsyslogd
1324 root      20   0  114m 1380  764 S  0.0  0.3   0:00.84 crond
1966 vagrant   20   0  105m 1880 1536 S  0.0  0.4   0:00.12 bash
1962 root      20   0 95788 3740 2832 S  0.0  0.7   0:00.18 sshd
1965 vagrant   20   0 95788 1748  836 S  0.0  0.3   0:00.11 sshd
1323 postfix   20   0 78868 3280 2448 S  0.0  0.7   0:00.00 qmgr
1322 postfix   20   0 78800 3232 2408 S  0.0  0.6   0:00.00 pickup
1314 root      20   0 78720 3252 2400 S  0.0  0.6   0:00.01 master
1238 root      20   0 64116 1180  512 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.80 sshd
```

This is on a rather small vagrant instance:

```
$ cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:         502412 kB
MemFree:          350976 kB
Buffers:           27148 kB
Cached:            45668 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:            45240 kB
Inactive:          39616 kB
Active(anon):      12164 kB
Inactive(anon):       44 kB
Active(file):      33076 kB
Inactive(file):    39572 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:       1048568 kB
SwapFree:        1048568 kB
Dirty:                 4 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
```